# Find multiple controls with by partially matching their name

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.5

I currently have 100+ labels, with names like:

```
labelNumber1 
labelNumber2 
labelNumber3 
labelNumber4 
....
labelLetter1
labelLetter2 
labelLetter3 
labelLetter4
....
```

How would I find all the labels that have "Number" in the controls name?
Instead of having to type out labelNumber1.text = "hello", etc.

I have tried regex and foreach with wild cards but did not succeed.
I have looked on msdn.microsoft.com about using regex with a control.

Comment: reflect your form class

Comment: Describe "to find all the label controls" in more details what you want

Comment: so if they are all labelNumber#  then you know the you can use <Control>.Name.Substring with the control to extract the Number or Letter text since they are both 6 characters. Like  foreach (Control t in form.Controls) t.Name.Substring(5, 6).Equals("Number")

Comment: `foreach (Control t in form.Controls)` then check `t.Name`? You can also use Linq

Comment: Surely you can find them programmatically using `this.Controls` collection, but what do you want to do with them. Suppose the result is a list containing `textBox1`, `textBox2` , `comboBox1`. Then? Do you want to run the same logic against all selected controls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can loop through the Controls collection of the form and just check the name of each control that it contains something like 'Label'. or you could check that the control is a typeof TextBox, Label, etc.

E.g.

```
foreach (Control control in form.Controls)
{
    if (control.Name.ToUpper().Contains("[Your control search string here]"))
    {
        // Do something here.
    }


    if (control is TextBox) {
        // Do something here.
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your code input.
this is working great. i removed `ToUpper` and its working like i would like it to. :)

Comment: Yeah, I was just using the ToUpper() in case your naming convention was varied. You could have checked that it contains("LABEL") and it would have matched on any casing of your label's naming. If you want case sensitivity, then just remove the ToUpper(), of course.

Answer (score 0):

you can filter the list of controls to only return the labels.  You would also want to make sure the name is greater than 11 chars.

```
        List<Label> allNumberLabels = new List<Label>();
        foreach (Label t in this.Controls.OfType<Label>())
        {                
            if (t.Name.Length > 11)
            {
                if (t.Name.Substring(5, 6).Equals("Number"))
                {
                    allNumberLabels.Add(t);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I know this is an old answer and you probably can guess the reason for the comment. I was replying to a different question which was flagged as a duplicate of this one. This solution, although correct for OP's example, is way too specific to that one case. I would call it "an overfit", "high cost to maintain", "low reuse". I know present you would probably agree :)

Comment: @AlexC. no, I can't really guess the need to come back a year later to be honest.  As well as this bit of code wasn't supposed to be low reuse as it was for this user's instance of their problem...like most of the answers on this forum. Ludicrous that you came and down voted it because it didn't meet your requirements.

Comment: 7 years to be exact. You can make one short edit and I will remove the downvote.

Comment: It's only 2 points rep, and I stand by my comment. I wanted to explain why, since SO suggested it. Isn't this community about quality content?

Comment: @AlexC.  You do realize this was not the accepted answer right??....you sir are a special individual....

Comment: Thank you! :) I am the type of person why actually checks a full thread before adding an answer or using code off the internet.  I like to learn something while making the world a better place! Is that bad?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I am here now, and:

- The question asks about searching for multiple **controls**. This solution actually applies to any type of control.
- OP was conflicted between using "Contains" or regex. I vote for regex! **string.Contains** is a bad idea for this kind of filter, since "CoolButton" has a "Button" in it too"

Anyway, here is the code:

```
public List<TControlType> FindByPattern<TControlType>(string regexPattern)
  where TControlType:Control
{
   return Controls.OfType<TControlType>()
                  .Where(control => Regex.IsMatch(control.Name, regexPattern))
                  .ToList();
}
```

Usage:

```
//some regex samples you can test out
var startsWithLabel = $"^Label"; //Matches like .StartsWith()
var containsLabel = "Label"; //Matches like .Contains()
var startsWithLabelEndsWithNumber = "^Label.*\\d+&"; //matches Label8sdf12 and Label8
var containsLabelEndsWithNumber = "Label.*\\d+&"; //matches MyLabelRocks83475, MyLabel8Rocks54389, MyLabel8, Label8
var hasAnyNumber= "^CoolLabel\\d+$"; //matches CoolLabel437627

var labels = FindByPattern<Label>("^MyCoolLabel.*\\d+&");
var buttons = FindByPattern<Button("^AveragelyCoolButton.*\\d+&");
```