# Parsing textbox input value, separated with a comma, to an int[] array

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having troubles parsing values from a textbox to an int[] array. The idea is to gather the numbers provided by the user, having them separated with a comma, e.g.:

1,5,-3,7,2

to then build an int[] array from the data gathered. The array is then to be bubble sorted by an algorithm, which I sort of have figured out already while playing around in a console application. While trying to search for a solution, I've come up with something like:

```
private TextBox DU_58827_FindTextBox(string displayName)
        {

            TextBox sender = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find(displayName, true)[0];

            return sender;

        }

private Array BubbleSortSourceArrayCreation()
        {
            TextBox source = FindTextBox("ArrayTextBox");

            string[] sourceArray = source.Text.Split(new Char[] { ',' });

            int[] intsToSort = Array.ConvertAll(sourceArray, s => int.Parse(s));

            return intsToSort;
        }
```

but the string[] array does not seem to get filled with any data. Narrowing down the issue, there is no top-down constraint on how many numbers the user can put in the textbox. How can I approach the matter?

Thanks!

Comment: So, I tried this in C# interactive. (By the way, you can omit the type when creating the array in `.Split(new [] {','})`). I just typed a list of strings into a variable, and then Split it. It contained all the values. So, my suspicion is that your `source.Text` is not what you think. Can you set a breakpoint after the split and see what it contains? Or you could `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",sourceArray)); which should basically give you back your initial list.

Comment: Also, be careful with your split, if this is a hand-entered list, then it might have spaces after the commas, for instance. You will need to account for this. If the spaces aren't relevant I usually just do this: `myString.Split(new[] { ',',' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` which splits on both spaces and commans and then if it gives any empty or whitespace strings it removes them. (In case it's hard to read that's a char literal comma followed by a char literal space in the array there.)

Comment: I agree with shellybutterfly. The `FindTextBox`-method looks suspect, and I would highly recommend that you confirm that this actually produces the intended string. The rest of the code looks find as far as I can see, even if you should follow shellybutterflys suggestion about removeEmptyEntries.

Comment: Hey @shelleybutterfly, JonasH, thanks for the replies! My mistake, should've attached the FindTextBox method right off the bat (sorry, this is my first post :( ) - the method itself should locate the TextBox in a pointed GroupBox(displayName) of my Forms project. It seems to be functional, as it does work when it comes to finding other textboxes in the rest of program's functionalities just fine... I will try my best to apply your suggestions! Thanks again, I'll try to update further should I fail at doing so.

Comment: No problem! Adding the code clears it up a little and helps narrow down the problem. It's best to include as much information about what you have determined by debugging and all the relevant code in a question, but sometimes it's not entirely clear where the problem is. Cheers!

Comment: I mean, it seems clear that something isn't working with the find, so I think you can narrow it down by setting a breakpoint, or doing a `Console.WriteLine()` to check that the value of `displayName` is what you think it is. (The only other thing I can think of is if this function is in a control you derived from `TextBox`, in which case you need to check `this.Name` before your `Find()` call. ) Can you show us the code for whatever is calling `DU_58827_FindTextBox()` or at least the code that finds the `displayName`?

Comment: Oh, another thing is are you trying to match the key identically, or is it only partial? If it's only partial you probably will need to iterate through the controls collection itself. I found a possibly relevant answer if that's your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35950866/832859 .

Comment: Is this an mdi form with multiple windows? In that case I don't think Controls.Find will find the item without searching each child form. Just loop through the `.MdiChildren` and call `Control.Find` on them.

Comment: I saw someone that mentioned that you can do `.Controls.Add()` and manually add controls with matching names; also you might have your own user controls or controls in a library that have controls with matching names. You can just check the `.Length` of the array returned in `.Controls.Find()` to see if that's happening.  If that's the case, you'll have to figure out some way to distinguish which ones you want, which, again may require looping the forms.